# Cannot add keyboard

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard, nokia-lumia-630

I have Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.10586.164) on Lumia 630. When I want to add another keyboard (Czech but I try some others) I get error 80070020. I tried to set time to manual, check regional settings, restart mobile, tried to add keyboard many times and nothing helps. I can update Windows and install new apps from store but I cannot add any keyboard except default english.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  changing the TImezone. A user has [reported](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/error-80070020/fd17ce84-88c0-4ed6-a0cd-85504f15e10d) that it solved the problem and 3 others have found that helpful in MS community.

Comment: I try it now but still same error.

Comment: I did factory reset and than I didn't  recover backup. After instalation completes I was able to add additional keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I did check for last updates and install them.
After factory reset I can add additional keyboards without problems.