# Can't downloads keyboards in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, keyboard, reset

My Blu Win HD LTE got bricked during a hard reset yesterday. I recovered it using the WDRT tool which put it back into Win8.1 Update 2. I updated it again until I could find no more updates.

While everything works fine, I am not able to install the Hinglish (Hinglish = Hindi + English) keyboard on my phone. It was there before my phone got bricked ( I don't remember how but since I typed on it most of the time, I know for sure it was there). Whenever I try to download the Hinglish keyboard or any keyboard, for instance, I get this error -

> The text suggestions update for this keyboard couldn't be installed

Seems like quite a lot of people have had this issue and the workaround seems to be to become an insider. But I don't want insider upgrades (yet), and in case I do become an insider, I will have to reset my phone to stop getting updates, which will start the problem over again.
And yeah just in case, I have tried soft resetting.

My OS build - 10.0.14393.693
Model - Blu Win HD LTE

Comment: Related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/cannot-add-keyboard

Comment: @User5 Not sure this is a duplicate, as the stated build is after the build that the issue on the linked question was resolved in

Comment: @RowlandShaw I was 90% sure therefore I flagged the question and didn't vote to close directly. I never ever vote for a question  unless I have 100% surety. I also gave a related question which maybe usefulincase I'm wrong.

Comment: @User5 this isn't a duplicate. My build is a later one. Also it was stated that this issue was fixed in the Redstone build. Since I am on a later build, I don't think this is a duplicate